# Symfony2/Doctrine2: Issues managing multiple entity manager inside a listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm following that recipe  `http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/cookbook/blending-orm-and-mongodb-odm.html#event-subscriber` and when i get to the event subscriber i'm not able to inject the proper `entity manager`, the one named `$this->dm` initialized in the constructor.

As i understand, the entity manager used by the entity which is being loaded can be retrieved through `$em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();` then i need another one which i `inject` in the following manner:

```
    services:
        postload.listener:
        class: myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Listener\myEntityListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.foobar_entity_manager"
```

Those are my entity managers:

```
//orm.yml
        orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    myVendormyFooBarBundle:
                        prefix: "myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity"
                        type: annotation
                        is_bundle: true
                        dir: "Entity"
            foobar:
                connection: foobar
                mappings:
                    myVendormyFooBarBundle:
                        prefix: "myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View"
                        type: annotation
                        is_bundle: true
                        dir: "View"
```

When `injecting` the `foobar entity manager` using the above strategy i get the following error:

```
Circular reference detected for service "postload.listener", path: "routing.loader -> routing.db.loader -> doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> postload.listener -> doctrine.orm.fooba_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.foobar_connection".
```

That's `myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Listener\myEntityListener` class:

```
    class myFooBarEntityListener
    {

        public function __construct( \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em )
        {
            $this->em = $em;
        }

        public function postLoad( LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs )
        {
            $myEntity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

            if( $myEntity instanceof \myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity\myEntity )
            {
                $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
                $fooBarReflProp = $em->getClassMetadata( 'myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity\myEntity' )->reflClass->getProperty( 'FooBarEntity' );
                $fooBarReflProp->setAccessible( true );
                $fooBarEntity = $this->em->getRepository( 'myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View\myFooBarEntity' )->findOneBy( array( 'id' => $myEntity->getFooBarEntityId() ) );
                $fooBarReflProp->setValue( $myEntity, $fooBarEntity );
            }
        }
    }
```

Also to avoid the `circular reference error` i've tried `not` to inject the `foobar entity manager` and get it  through `LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs`:

```
    class myFooBarEntityListener
    {

        public function postLoad( LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs )
        {
            $myEntity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

            if( $myEntity instanceof \myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity\myEntity )
            {
                $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
                $fooBarReflProp = $em->getClassMetadata( 'myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity\myEntity' )->reflClass->getProperty( 'FooBarEntity' );
                $fooBarReflProp->setAccessible( true );
                //NOTICE HOW HERE I SHOULD GET THE PROPER ENTITY MANAGER THROUGH $eventArgs
                $fooBarEntity = $eventArgs->getEntityManager('foobar')->getRepository( 'myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View\myFooBarEntity' )->findOneBy( array( 'id' => $myEntity->getFooBarEntityId() ) );
                $fooBarReflProp->setValue( $myEntity, $fooBarEntity );
            }
        }
    }
```

That last implementation throughs me the following error:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Class myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View\myFooBarEntity is not a valid entity or mapped super class.") in "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig" at line 28.`

The above error is caused by `$fooBarEntity = $eventArgs->getEntityManager('foobar')->getRepository( 'myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View\myFooBarEntity' )->findOneBy( array( 'id' => $myEntity->getFooBarEntityId() ) );` because when i place echo 'hello';die(); just before that line  the error is not thrown but when placed just after the line the error is thrown and `hello` is not shown. The error makes me think that although i'm explicitly getting the `foobar` connection through `$eventArgs->getEntityManager('foobar')` it is still giving me the `default` `connection/entity manager`.

In order to double check `myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View\myFooBarEntity` syntax i went to `octrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain` and placed the following code:

```
    if( strpos( $className, 'myFooBarEntity' ) )
    {
        echo 'Class: '.$className."\n\n";
        foreach ($this->_drivers as $namespace => $driver)
        {
            echo 'namespace: '.$namespace."\n";
            $bool = strpos($className, $namespace);
            var_dump($bool);
            echo "\n\n";
        }
    }
    die();
```

That DriverChain code gives me the following, that's why i think 'foobar' connection is never used or symfony has some kind of bug interpreting `orm.yml` file which defines the entity managers plus namespaces to use.

class: myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View\myFooBarEntity

namespace: myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity
bool(false)

If i look foor the `entity` word inside `myVendor\myFooBarBundle\View\myFooBarEntity` i just find `@ORM\Entity` for the entity definition and also `@ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity=.....)` for the relation with another entity.

I hope someone can help, as it's driving me crazy. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

```
services:
    postload.listener:
    class: myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Listener\myEntityListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
    arguments:
        - @doctrine
```

My listener:

```
namespace myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Listener\myEntityListener;

use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;

class myFooBarEntityListener
{

    private $reg;

    public function __construct(Registry $reg)
    {
        //dont't put your entitymanager otherwise a loop appear during creation
        $this->reg = $reg;
    }

    public function postLoad( LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs )
    {
        $myEntity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

        if( $myEntity instanceof \myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity\myEntity )
        {

            $em = $this->reg->getEntityManager('not_default');
            $userPointdbManager = $em->getRepository('FullerUserBundle:UserPointdb');

            ....
        }
    }
}
```

You can use several entity managers now.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your problem:

You're trying to work on Entites that are not managed by the entityManager you're working with.

The reason is that in your first example, you ony work on the service `doctrine.orm.foobar_entity_manager`, that is not aware of `myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity` entites.

In second one you try to access different entityManagers using: `$eventArgs->getEntityManager('foobar')` but this won't work. EventArgs is attached to only ONE entityManager, and there is no argument (like 'foobar') to access another one.

So the best solution I see here is to act like in your first idea, but injecting both entityMangers:

```
services:
    postload.listener:
    class: myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Listener\myEntityListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
    arguments:
        - "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
        - "@doctrine.orm.foobar_entity_manager"
```

If you have cyclic dependencies detection, try to inject the `doctrine` service, which is an instance of `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've already tried it all, injecting both entity managers, injecting service container and then get doctrine service, injecting doctrine service and then getting both entity managers but i'm always getting the Circular reference error. Do you know what else can i do? Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Finally i took a look at `l3pp4rd DoctrineBehaviours` and created a more advanced listener based on his structure and had no problem obtaining both connections from `doctrine` service.

Comment: So can any of these answers be marked as accepted or at least your solution be posted, @user846226 ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set Registry as parameter, but RegistryInterface (use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface)

Answer (score 0):

The last example started to work for me after changing
use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry; to use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;.

So it should be:

```
namespace myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Listener\myEntityListener;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry

class myFooBarEntityListener
{

    private $reg;

    public function __construct(Registry $reg)
    {
        //dont't put your entitymanager otherwise a loop appear during creation
        $this->reg = $reg;
    }

    public function postLoad( LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs )
    {
        $myEntity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

        if( $myEntity instanceof \myVendor\myFooBarBundle\Entity\myEntity )
        {

            $em = $this->reg->getEntityManager('not_default');
            $userPointdbManager = $em->getRepository('FullerUserBundle:UserPointdb');

            ....
        }
    }
}
```